# LINQ expression result implicit to inherited object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I've an **Document** object and **User** object, generated by Entity Framework Model Generator.

I want to get **Document** list, plus *userCount* created according to this Document.

So, I've created new object *DocumentWithUserCount*:

```
public class DocumentWithUserCount:Document
{
    public uAmount {get;set}
}
```

And LINQ to retain data (below code, I need your help) :

```
    var ed = (from d in _entity.Document
     join p in _entity.User[get DocID and count by this docID ] on d.RID equals p.DocID         
select new DocumentWithUserCount(xxxx)).ToList();
```

How to do this?

**EDIT:**
Simply I want to do equivalent code below with LINQ.

```
    SELECT d.*, p.* from Document d INNER JOIN (select docid, count(RID) as uAmount from User
    GROUP BY DocID) p ON d.RID=p.docid
```

Comment: Do you really want to _convert_ your returned Documents to DocumentWithUserCount objects? Because that will require copying and losing contact with originals (and their Tracking).

Comment: @HenkHolterman I want to get (Document.*, p.Count as count) where count is (userCount according to each document).And I don't know, how to simply to do this. Thanks.

Comment: What is `enSpecificDocument`? Do you have navigation properties in Document and User entities?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka no, I haven't navigation property between Document and User entities yet.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka enSpecificDocument it's mistake. fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that inheritance is the wrong tool here. Use composition instead. And It's not clear if you even nneed the Join, there should be a navigation property:

```
var eds = from d in _entity.Document       
   select new { Document=d, UserCount=d.Users.Count() };  // anon type
```

or

```
public class DocumentWithUserCount  //:Document
{
    public Doucument { get; set; }
    public int Amount {get;set}
}
var eds = from d in _entity.Document       
   select new DocumentWithUserCount { Document=d, Amount=d.Users.Count() };
```

Comment: I personally prefer that too.

Answer (score 1):

Does this not work?

```
var documentWithUserCount =
    from Document d in _entity.Document
    join p in _entity.User on d.RID equals p.DocID
    select new DocumentWithUserCount(d, p.Count());
```

Add a constructor in DocumentWithUserCount as follows

```
public DocumentWithUserCount(Document doc, int count) : base(d)
{
    uAmount = count;
}
```

Add a constructor in Document that will take a Document and set the appropriate properties.